# how to avoid MULE ESB to Shut down by it self after inactivity period

Tags: java, mule

i'd developed a web services core using Mule ESB. This is an old project, it was migrated to a new server and now am having this new issue.

The Mule Stops by it self after a long period of inactivity, i had this issue a few years ago but am not able to solve it.

I know there was some configs to change in order to avoid this annoying behaviour.

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is how the log looks like:

```
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,515 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Disposing app 'integrador-catalogo'                      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,515 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing RegistryBro$
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,516 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.transport.quartz.QuartzConnector: Disconnected: QuartzCon$
{
  name=connector.quartz.mule.default
  lifecycle=stop
  this=5d697268
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[quartz]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,516 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing connector: $
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,516 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler scheduler-integrador-ca$
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,516 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler scheduler-integrador-ca$
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,517 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler scheduler-integrador-ca$
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,517 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Disconnected: FileConnector
{
  name=connector.file.mule.default
  lifecycle=stop
  this=84da512
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[file]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,518 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing connector: $
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,519 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector: Disconnected: HttpConnector
{
  name=connector.http.mule.default
  lifecycle=stop
  this=27806c10
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[http]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,519 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing connector: $
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,519 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.util.monitor.ExpiryMonitor: disposing monitor
...

INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:14,709 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.DefaultMuleContext:
**********************************************************************
* Application "integrador-catalogo" shut down normally on: 3/14/16   *
* 2:30 PM                                                            *
* Up for: 1 days, 1 hours, 0 mins, 2.308 sec                         *
**********************************************************************
```

EDIT 1 03-17-2016

Here is the part of the log when the shutdown process starts:

```
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,693 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.DefaultMuleContext:
**********************************************************************
* Application: integrador-catalogo                                   *
* OS encoding: UTF-8, Mule encoding: UTF-8                           *
*                                                                    *
* Agents Running:                                                    *
*   JMX Agent                                                        *
*   Wrapper Manager: Mule PID #1814, Wrapper PID #1812               *
**********************************************************************
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,702 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Stopping app 'integrador-catalogo'                       +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,704 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Stopping flow: insertAddress
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,704 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector: Removing listener on endpointUri: http://localhost:8081/insertAddress
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,705 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Stopping: 'null'. Object is: HttpMessageReceiver
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,706 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing: 'null'. Object is: HttpMessageReceiver
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,706 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver: Closed Tcp port
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,707 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.processor.SedaStageLifecycleManager: Stopping service: insertAddress.stage1
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,865 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager: Stopping component: component.1597401338
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,865 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager: Stopping component: component.1129596634
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,866 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Stopping flow: DeleteAddressByParameter
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,866 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector: Removing listener on endpointUri: http://localhost:8081/DeleteAddressByParameter
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,866 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Stopping: 'null'. Object is: HttpMessageReceiver
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,866 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing: 'null'. Object is: HttpMessageReceiver
INFO  2016-03-14 14:30:13,866 [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver: Closed Tcp port
```

Comment: Are you running the project on Mule standalone server or Anypoint studio ? How long period it takes to shutdown ?

Comment: I Guess standslone, it usually takes 1 day without requests to stop it self

Comment: Can you add the part of the log just before Mule starts to shut down?

Comment: Hi Ale, i just added the part of the log that shows when the process starts the shutdown process

Comment: What OS are you running on? How do you start Mule?

Comment: @DavidDossot Am running this project on Ubuntu Linux to start mule and i start mule by executing this line sudo /var/lib/integrador/mule-standalone-3.3.1/bin/mule restart

Comment: You show the shutdown part of the log but not what happens just before that. There might be some information there about the triggering of the shutdown.

Comment: @AlejandroDobniewski From my experience there is no pre-shutdown information logged in neither - the app log nor the standalone runtime log... It just silently stops.

Comment: you are running Mule standalone, what is in the mule_ee.log at the same time? Mule 3.3 is an older, currently unsupported version. Have you tried with a newer one?